# cardinality for parameter 2 does not match the cardinality declared in the function's signature: (...)

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have the following function that should transform xml2 to a div, using xsl2.

```
declare function app:includeContent($node as node(), $model as map(*)) {
      let $ref := xs:string(request:get-parameter("document", ""))
      let $xml2 := doc(concat(concat($config:app-root, "/resources/content.xml"),$ref))
      let $xsl2 := doc(concat($config:app-root,"/resources/xslt/headerToHtml.xsl"))
      let $params2 :=
      <parameters>
         {for $p in request:get-parameter-names()
          let $val := request:get-parameter($p,())
          where  not($p = ("document","directory","stylesheet"))
          return
             <param name="{$p}"  value="{$val}"/>
         }
       </parameters>
         return
           transform:transform($xml2, $xsl2, $params2)
             };
```

Why would I get the following output?

err:XPTY0004 checking function parameter 2 in call

> transform:transform($xml2, $xsl2, $params2): XPTY0004: The actual
> cardinality for parameter 2 does not match the cardinality declared in
> the function's signature: transform:transform($node-tree as node()*,
> $stylesheet as item(), $parameters as node()?) node()?. Expected
> cardinality: exactly one, got 0. [at line 110, column 36, source:
> /db/apps/boos/modules/app.xql]

(line 110 is the `transform:transform`-line and column 36 should be the p in `$params` )

I do not get any errors when saving the file this function resides in (app.xql)

Comment: It sounds as if the `$xsl2` variable is bound to an empty sequence, I am not sure why that could happen with above code. Any chance the XSLT is not found in the DB?

Comment: Yeah, Atom Editor did not sync that file to my exist-db installation. However, I haven't figured out why, but this keeps happening from time to time ...

Comment: Strange indeed. For readability I'd recommend to write

`let $xsl2 := doc( $config:app-root || "/resources/xslt/headerToHtml.xsl")`

Comment: Out of curiosity what is in `$config:app-root` ?

Comment: @DiZzZz The `config` module is created automatically in eXist-db when you set up a new application with the application wizard. `$config:app-root` holds the absolute path to your application's root collection, e.g. `/db/apps/my-application`.

Comment: The key is “eg”... that is an assumption, which I wanted to tackle.

Comment: @DiZzZz Sorry, could you please elaborate?